# Need an Index to speed up a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL query that takes long time to process.

```
 Select Count(*) from Table1 
 Where Col1='abc'
 Or (Col2='xyz' And Col3='mnl' And Col4='efg')
 Or (Col2='xyz' And Col3='mnl' And Col5='ijk')
```

I need an index for this query. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need a free pony and unlimited pizza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your query plan to use indexes, you may need to create multiple indexes, and break up the "OR" conditions in the predicate into separate queries, and combine the results with `UNION ALL` operators.

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS cnt
  FROM ( 
         SELECT SUM(1) AS cnt
           FROM Table1
          WHERE Col1 = 'abc'
          UNION ALL
         SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM Table1
          WHERE Col2='xyz'
            AND Col3='mnl'
            AND (Col4='efg' OR Col5='ijk')
            AND NOT (Col1 <=> 'abc')
       ) s
```

NOTE: use a "UNION ALL" operator, to avoid reducing the count by half, in the corner case where both queries happen to return the same value, and be sure to include the inequality test on Col1 in the second query, so row don't get double counted.

These should be sufficient covering indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX Table1_IX1 ON Table1 (Col1)

CREATE INDEX Table1_IX2 ON Table1 (Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col1)
```

Verify that each subquery can make use of the index, by examining the output from an EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

No index is really going to help that.

Change it to this:-

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE Col1='abc'
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE (Col2='xyz' And Col3='mnl' And Col4='efg')
    Or (Col2='xyz' And Col3='mnl' And Col5='ijk')
) Sub1
```

Then add one index on column Col1. Add another index over 3 columns, Col2, Col3 and Col4

Your issue is that MySQL can only use one index on an occurrence of a table in a query. Hence with your OR it can't use a useful index. This splits it to 2 queries each using an occurrence of Table1, hence it can use an index on each.